# uniformly continuous functions $X$

Tags: real-analysis

theorem :

let $X$ be a metric space such that every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous. then $X$ is compact.

how can proof this theorem. 
we know every continuous function on comapct metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe what you want is to show that: "If $X$ is a metric space such that every continuous function on $X$ is *bounded*, then $X$ is compact".

Answer (score 2):

The statement is wrong. Take any infinite set $X$ together with the discrete metric $d$. Then for every metric space $Y$ every map $(X,d) \to Y$ is uniformly continuous. But $(X,d)$ is not compact.